# New Relic or Bugsnag?

Tags: newrelic, bugsnag

Are Bugsnag and New Relic counterparts or they serve different purposes? Should I use them both on my website? I couldn't find a quick answer regarding this on Google search.

I have a laravel5 app and I am on my quest of searching for a good tool to monitor my app performance and catch errors. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the record, I disagree with the close vote for the question being "primarily opinion-based". I'm sure there's an objective way to compare the two and put them into a useful context.

Answer (score 9):

Bugsnag co-founder here. Many of our customers use Bugsnag side-by-side with New Relic. Bugsnag focuses on actionable error monitoring, whereas New Relic's focus is on performance.

Answer (score -6):

There are also other tools out there that can help you with PHP monitoring. I am working for dynatrace as a performance advocate. Check out our technical blogs and consider it for your tool evaluation: http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2014/04/16/top-3-php-performance-tips-for-continuous-delivery/ & http://apmblog.dynatrace.com/2014/10/30/proper-configuration-running-php-nginx/

Comment: The question was about New Relic vs BugSnag, not DynaTrace.